# Misaligned chart in the habits agenda mode in orgmode

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-habit

After upgrade from Ubuntu 18 to 20 my agenda habits chart now is broken. Any ideas in how to fix that?

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce this: When the headline is too long, it gets cut off at just the point where the consistency graph starts (at the column specified by `org-habit-graph-column`). The font looks like a fixed-width font, so that's not the problem. Why are you lines wrapped where they are? And what are the characters between the end of the headline and the beginning of the consistency graph?

Comment: Why are you lines wrapped where they are? - Good question! - what are the characters between the end of the headline and the beginning of the consistency graph? - white spaces. I edited my question and added a new figure. Have a look.

Comment: I tested in the Q4OS and I have the same issue. Maybe my .emacs file? My .emacs file can be found here: https://github.com/felipelalli/micaroni/blob/master/emacs/.emacs

Comment: So does it work properly if you start emacs with `-q`? And I can see it's white space, but is it just spaces, or does it include tabs?

Comment: With `-q` option the chart does not even appears. Only white spaces.

Comment: Then write a minimal init file to do just the necessary initializations and invoke `emacs -q -l /path/to/minimal/init.el` file. The object of this is to eliminate the bulk of your init file from consideration. Then if you can get the correct result with the miminal file, you can assert that your real init file is the cause. You can then bisect your way through your init file to discover which part of it causes the problem.

Comment: @NickD thank you for the tip. I didn't try it before because I thought it wasn't related with `.emacs` because I didn't change it recently. But old configurations just didn't work with my new OS configuration (150% HDPI scaled). I posted the answer, but feel free to copy/paste and create a new answer. I'd accept it as the correct answer. If you do that, I'd erase my answer.

Comment: No need to do that - glad that you figured it out. (edit added) And now that I've looked at your answer in more detail, I don't think I could have answered it! So I'm glad that my comments pointed you in the right direction so that the question *could be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @NickD commentary I was able to figure out the issue.

**TL;DL:** the problem was with the variable `org-habit-graph-column` that was set to **80** and I just changed to **default** (removed the line). I tested with **40** and it worked fine as well. That was the first suspicion of @NickD in his first commentary.

Fortunately I keep track of my `.emacs` changes in my personal repo. So, I used the [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) tool to find the bad commit. The bad commit was this one: [**Improving params of habits**](https://github.com/felipelalli/micaroni/commit/c47027cfb0299c6ff4b699c73093c2c59987296e) introduced in Oct 24, 2018. Maybe this wasn't an issue before because now I have scaled my screen to 150% in the new Ubuntu installation.

The first thing I did was to remove the line with `org-habit-graph-column` and everything just went fine. Then, I changed others parameters too, just to fit better in the screen, in this commit: [**Fixing chart in agenda to 150% scale screens (HDPI)**](https://github.com/felipelalli/micaroni/commit/f43d31aa6c1a1849d51727110f446f38726a149c).

Comment: BTW, you can [accept your own answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer): I don't think you gain any reputation but it has the great advantage of indicating to future visitors that this question has an answer that the OP has found acceptable.

Comment: I should have added that you have to wait 48 hours before accepting your own answer.